# Integrate nhibernate with Unity3D

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, nhibernate

I am trying to implement Nhibernate to my Unity3D project.

My main project is compiled to Unity 3.5 net full Base Class Libraries
My second project (the one with Nhibernate reference) is compiled to .Net Framework 3.5 (.dll file is deployed to Aseets/Plugins folder)
I am using Nhibernate 3.4.0.4000

Unity3D gives error:

"[...]
Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies."

So I copy NHibernate.dll and Iesi.Collections.dll to Assets/Plugins folder as well.

But it produce another error:

"

Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.

at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (bool)

at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in :0

at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in :0

at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespace (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in :0

at Mono.CSharp.GlobalRootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx) [0x00000] in :0

at Mono.CSharp.Driver.LoadReferences () [0x00000] in :0

at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in :0

at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0

The class System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler could not be loaded, used in System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
The class System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters could not be loaded, used in System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

"

What depends on IConfigurationSectionHandler and where can I find it?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the compiled DLLs file in the `Assets` folder not the `Assets/Plugins` folder. If you are using version 3.4.0, before compiling, open `Logging.cs` you need and change [baseDir](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Logging.cs) string from `string baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;` to `string baseDir = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;` in line 86. It worked for this [person](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-and-fluentnhibernate-possible.305098/).

Also make sure to have the .NET database connector DLL(`MySQL.Data.dll`) in the `Assets` folder.

**EDIT**:

You must also change Api Compatibility Level from **.Net 2.0 Subset** to **.Net 2.0** as noted by OP.

Comment: Hi, thanks for fast answer. Unfortunatelly it do not helps. I still have an error: The class System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler could not be loaded, used in System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
The class System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters could not be loaded, used in System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Comment: Downlaod the  nhibernate 3.4.0 version  and try again.

Comment: Setting Api Compatibility Level from .Net 2.0 subset to .Net 2.0 solved the problem.

Comment: But your problem cannot be solved without putting the DLL's in the `Assets/Plugins` directory and also making the code changes in my answer. If this contributed to your solution, you can accept it as the answer. Simply changing it to  Net 2.0 did not solve the problem.